# How to make Bootstrap 5.0 (beta 3) navbar link active with JS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 (Beta 3 - no JQuery) on a static site, and I need to make a navbar link active.  I want to do this in JS as I don't want to have a special navbar for each page.  For example, when the user is on the **about.html** page, the **About** in the navbar will be toggled to active as in:

```
<li><a class="nav-link active" href="about.html">About</a></li>
```

**HTML Snippet**

```
      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>  <!--  "scrollto active" below -->
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li> 
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="team.html">Your Team</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
          <!-- <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><strong>Client Login</strong></a></li> -->
        </ul>
        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
      </nav>
```

**Current JS Code**

```
var filename = window.location.pathname;
// This gives me:  /about.html

var link = filename.substring(1, (filename.length-5));
//This gives me:  about

var x = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];//.getElementsByTagName("li")[0]; //.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]; // .getAttribute("href");
// I tried using the uncommented code with .getElementsByTagName("li").getElementsByTagname(a")[0].getAttribute("href")
// but I just get 5 NULLs (I have 5 links in the navbar)

var lists = x.children;
// This gives me an HTML Collection, right?

for (let i = 1; i < x.childElementCount; i++) {
         
    console.log(lists[i]);
    //What I want to do is check what the href text is
    //Pseudocode:
    //if (the_href_value == link variable) {
    //  add " active" to the <a> class
    //}

    console.log(lists[i].getAttribute("href"));
    //this gives me NULL
};
```

I feel I'm close, but after bashing my head against this, I'm officially asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can simplify it to..

```
var filename = window.location.pathname;
var link = filename.substring(1, (filename.length-5));
let navlink = document.querySelector('[href^='+link+']')
navlink.classList.add('active')
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/IANMr7uMA2)